# Correcting jQuery syntax: Checking two select box option values and writing a separate input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#gender').change(function() {
            if($(this).find('option:selected').val() == 'Male' && $('#size').find('option:selected').val() == 'Large') {
                $('#results').val() == 'Size Large - The Most Basic Size'
            }
            else if($(this).find('option:selected').val() == 'Female' && $('#size').find('option:selected').val() == 'Large') {
                $('#results').val() == 'Size Large - The Second Most Basic Size'
            }
            else {
                $('#results').val() == 'Nothing'
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

The goal is simple: Check the values of two select boxes and change the value in the #results input with the first select change function. This is probably pretty simple but I know I'm doing it wrong since it's not working....;)

Comment: Can you post the HTML up too please.

Comment: In addition to the correct answers below, I also noticed I was using a .text parameter but asking the jQuery to check the .val instead. Posting the HTML, like DaveHogan suggested, would have caught that error as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set value of result in wrong way. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#gender').change(function() {
            if($(this).find('option:selected').val() == 'Male' && $('#size').find('option:selected').val() == 'Large') {
                $('#results').val('Size Large - The Most Basic Size');
            }
            else if($(this).find('option:selected').val() == 'Female' && $('#size').find('option:selected').val() == 'Large') {
                $('#results').val('Size Large - The Second Most Basic Size');
            }
            else {
                $('#results').val('Nothing');
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You know, I had that originally but also had if($(this).find('option:selected').val('Male') && ... and it wasn't working. So I changed it all to .val() ==. Thanks for pointing that out. I guess the #results needs .val('something') and the conditions need .val() ==. Could you possibly tell me why or point me in the direction where I could find this answer? Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the string as parameter:

```
$('#results').val('Size Large - The Most Basic Size');
```

Note that using `find` is not necessary, `val` returns the value of selected option:

```
if ($(this).val() == 'Male' && $('#size').val() == 'Large') {
```

Comment: Hmmmmm. I commented before I saw your edit. That's interesting. I was always working that .val couldn't find the option and you needed to find first. I just checked and you are indeed right. Makes my code cleaner. I wish I could accept two answers.